# Tiered formula in Excel

Tags: excel, algorithm

I was hoping someone could help me with this conundrum as l feel like l've been spinning my wheels all day with this one. Here's the scenario and l'll try and keep it simple.

Lets say, l currently have 1.5 million subscribers a month and l get paid on a minimum guarantee (MG) of 2.1 million subscribers a month.

Those 2.1 million subscribers are broken down into 500k increments i.e. 
Tier 1 0-500k           l get paid £0.20 per subscriber
Tier 2 500k-1,000k      l get paid £0.19 per subscriber
Tier 3 1,000k - 1,500k  l get paid £0.18 per subscriber
Tier 4 1,500k - 2,000k  I get paid £0.17 per subscriber

Anything above 2.1 million subscribers is incremental income (say at £0.16 per subscriber) but l'll always be paid for the MG subs no matter what.

This is my attempted logic at the formula:
IF actual subs are > MG subs then actual subs subtracted from Tier 4 subs (2,000) x cost per subscriber. (I'm subtracting actuals from the Tier 4 subs because l've already factored in the fees l'm being paid on these subscribers). IF that's not true i.e. IF actual subs are < MG subs then MG subs subtracted Tier 4 subs (2,000) x cost per subscriber.

It's tricky to explain and if l could l'd attach a spreadsheet to show you. The complexity is really having something flexible enough to handle changes to Tiers and Tier sizes as well as changes in MG levels. If you have anything better or suggestion to improve that would be a great help.

Thanks for your help,

M.

Answer (score 0):

Do a table like the image

[image]

On E5 put

```
=(E2-VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,1,TRUE)+1)*VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,2,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(E2,A:C,3,TRUE)
```

The formula may vary because in portuguese they are a bit different, but I think I got it right.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the prompt response. I like it!! Your picture looks like me all of today :)

Answer (score 0):

since you are guaranteed the MG, the MG can be computed as

```
=SUMPRODUCT({500000,500000,500000,500000},{0.2,0.19,0.18,0.17})
```

which yield 370,000 pound sterling and will be constant.

so if you actually have `x` subscribers (where value `x` written in cell `A1`), you can compute additional return by

```
=MAX((A1-2000000)*0.16,0)
```

which will always yield a positive value.

So total return is the sum of the above two results.

```
= 370 + MAX((A1-2000000)*0.16,0)
```

BR~

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I like the use of sum product, l had though about using that but l need to show the breakout of the tiers. The max formula is great and works perfectly. That was my largest obstacle and is much simpler that the formula that l was using. Thanks again. M.